# Which exit method in .NET is the best to use?

Tags: .net, exit

There are many ways to exit a program..I found these one's and i geuss there are more.

- End
- Application.Exit
- Me.Close
- Form.Close

What are the main difference between these one's and which one do you recommend to simply close the program?

Comment: They don't do quite the same thing... closing a form _may_ be the same thing as closing the application if it's the only form, but not necessarily. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not something in particular...Just wondering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the main(or last) form of your app and it it configured to also close the app when you close this form then calling `Close()` on the form object will be enough.

`Application.Exit()` will send a `FormClosing` followed by a `FormClosed` events to all forms in the application before it shuts down all the message loops that are running. Hence if you have code in the `FormClosing` event your app might not exit, but otherwise the application will close just like in the case of `Form.Close()`.

`Me` is actually `this` from C# so it is essentially the same as Form.Close();

So to sum up, if you don't have any special needs, calling Close() on the main form is the most desirable way: it is the most widely used, the most intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

End is a Visual Basic keyword.  It calls Environment.Exit(), a way to instantly kill the program.

Application.Exit() tries to close all the opened forms.  It fires the FormClosing event, if any form cancels it then the app won't exit.  It is the friendly and recommended way to exit.

Me.Close() only closes one form object, whichever is *Me*.  The application will only exit if that's the only form object that's left or if it is the main window (the first one created) and the project's Shutdown mode setting is "When startup form closes".

Form.Close() is not valid code.  An object reference is required.

Comment: Even Environment.Exit() can't guarantee that the application will exit. I've encountered several situations where, after calling Environment.Exit(), some unmanaged code would hang the app, waiting on some wait handle. In that buggy situation, Environment.FailFast() and Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill() do terminate the process.

Comment: +1 for "End is a Visual Basic keyword. It calls Environment.Exit()"